# Liquibase incremental snapshots

Tags: liquibase

We've got a rather interesting use-case where we're using Liquibase to deploy a database for our application but we're not actually in control of the database. This means that we've got to add in a lot of extra logic around each time we run Liquibase to avoid encountering any errors during the actual run. One way we've done that is that we're generating snapshots of what the DB should look like for each release of our product and then comparing that snapshot with the running DB to know that it's in a compatible state. The snapshot files for our complete database aren't gigantic but if we have to have a full one for every possible release that could cause our software package to get large in the future with dead weight.

We've looked at using the Linux patch command to create offset files as the deltas between these files will typically be very small (i.e. 1 column change, etc.) but the issues are the generated IDs in the snapshot that are not consistent across runs:

```
    "snapshotId": "aefa109",
    "table": "liquibase.structure.core.Table#aefa103"
```

Is there any way to force the IDs to be consistent or attack this problem in a different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we should change how we think about PROD deployments.  When I read:

> This means that we've got to add in a lot of extra logic around each time we run Liquibase to avoid encountering any errors during the actual run.

This is sort of an anti-pattern in the world of Liquibase.  Typically, Liquibase is used in a CI/CD pipeline and deployments of SQL are done on "lower environments" to practice for the PROD deployment (which many do not have control over, so your situation is a common one).

When we try to accommodate the possible errors during a PROD deployment, I feel we already are in a bad place with our deployment automation.  We should have been testing the deploys on lower environmets that look like PROD.

For example your pipeline for your DB could look like:

- DEV->QA->PROD
- Create SQL for deployment in a changelog
- DEV & QA seeded with restore from current state of PROD (maybe minus the row data)
- You would have all control in DEV (the wild west)
- Less control of QA (typically only by QA)
- Iterate till you have no errors in your DEV & QA env
- Deploy to PROD

If you still have errors, I would argue that you must root cause why and resolve so you can have a pipeline that is automatable.

Hope that helps,

Ronak

Comment: I completely understand your point but that would assume that we have complete control over all environments. We are using Liquibase along with our product where we deploy to on-prem customer environments that are owned by them. We are trying to come up with a method that allows us to have a single Liquibase implementation that can accommodate various potential starting points/etc. I know this isn't a standard use-case and it's why we have a somewhat strange question.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Okay, with that knowledge, I recommend checking out this page:
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html
Particularly, the use case this is good for is stated as: "
    Document what assumptions the writers of the changelog had when creating it.
    Enforce that those assumptions are not violated by users running the changelog.
    Perform data checks before performing an unrecoverable change such as dropTable.
    Control what changesets are run and not run based on the state of the database.
"

Comment: Yeah, we're definitely using pre-conditions but essentially are trying to make a "pre-check" script that will validate the status of the database using snapshot comparison since that's a wholesale comparison. That way we can report on things that will cause failures before actually encountering any and will result in a better experience. Hence the question about how to optimize the snapshot comparison itself.